# jQuery toggle body class?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I’m trying to build a simple list that when you click a button it adds a class to the body for styling purposes, i.e click uk it adds uk to the body class and i can style that.

However, if you click u.s it removes the uk from the body class and adds in the us class instead and so on and so fourth for any click. Also removes itself if clicked, so goes back to original state.

I can get one to toggle but other seem to be ignored.

```
$( "#country-id" ).click(function() {
 $( '#country-code' ).toggleClass( "uk" );
 $( '#country-code' ).toggleClass( "us" );
 $( '#country-code' ).toggleClass( "aus" );
 $( '#country-code' ).toggleClass( "nz" );
});
```

I have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APAKL/2/) here, anyone mind helping?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/APAKL/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APAKL/3/

```
$("#country-id > li").click(function() {
    $('#country-code').toggleClass( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Or shorter with:

```
$("#country-id > li").click(function() {
    $('#country-code').toggleClass(this.id);
});
```

This targets the click event on the LIs (not the list). It takes the id of the clicked LI and uses it's `id` attribute as the class to add.

### If you only need one selected at a time:

You probably want to clear them all and add one instead:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APAKL/4/

```
$( "#country-id > li" ).click(function() {
    $( '#country-code' ).removeClass('uk us aus nz');
    $( '#country-code' ).addClass( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Which reduces to:

```
$( "#country-id > li" ).click(function() {
    $( '#country-code' ).removeClass('uk us aus nz').addClass( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Or even to:

```
$( "#country-id > li" ).click(function() {
    $( '#country-code' ).removeClass('uk us aus nz').addClass(this.id);
});
```